# Selected state to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add a selected state to a div. i.e add border to div that is clicked? Only display one at a time

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sPLDh/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="people">

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>John doe</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Peter Pan</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sally Hills</h2>
    </div>

    <p>John Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Peter Pan is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Sally Hills is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>Betty Boo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sm Hunt</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Paula Walls</h2>
    </div>

    <p>Betty Jones Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Sam Hunt is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Paula Walls is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.people{
width:500px;
}
.person{
width:33%;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
}
.people p{
display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.person img').click(function() {
    var index = $('.person img').index(this);
    $('.people p:visible').fadeOut('fast','linear').promise().done(function() {
        $('.people p:eq('+index+')').fadeIn('fast','linear');
    });
});
```

Comment: look at the [jQuery class manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

Comment: I would recommend listening to JavaScript's `click` event and adding a CSS class to the appropriate div in the event handler. Then, apply whatever styles you'd like to in your CSS.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy: Along with removing that class from all elements that currently have it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to add and remove border on the selected images.

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.active{
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.person img').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var index = $('.person img').index(this);
    $('.people p:visible').fadeOut('fast','linear').promise().done(function() {
        $('.people p:eq('+index+')').fadeIn('fast','linear');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your text was getting messed up when border was added. So try this...

In, `.people p`, add:

Add:

```
float:left;
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sPLDh/7/)**

Comment: Updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Append on the $('.person img').click function

```
$(".person").css("border", "0px");
$(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid #000");
```

so the function would look like

```
$('.person img').click(function() {
    var index = $('.person img').index(this);
    $('.people p:visible').fadeOut('fast','linear').promise().done(function() {
        $('.people p:eq('+index+')').fadeIn('fast','linear');
    });
    $(".person").css("border", "0px");
    $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid #000");
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not required if you are not supporting IE7 and below.
Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/76vLU/2/)

Markup:

```
<div class="people">

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0" />
        <h2>John doe</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0"/>
        <h2>Peter Pan</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person" >
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0"/>
        <h2>Sally Hills</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0"/>
        <h2>Betty Boo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0"/>
        <h2>Sm Hunt</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" tabindex="0"/>
        <h2>Paula Walls</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.person:focus{
    border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

JS:

```
var images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
images.forEach(function(image){
    image.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.focus();
    });
});
```

Please note the **tabindex** attribute used.

Comment: Doesn't work in FF... Works in Safari and Chrome though!

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick and short demo using addClass and removeClass to toggle css border for "div" being clicked.
HTML:

```
<div class="target">Click here to show its border!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.target{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".target").click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("class") == "target"){
         $(this).removeClass("target");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("target");
    }
});
```

Here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasperlee/NCS2g/